# Featured Products Code Feedback Needed: CE 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

The featured products code below seems to indicate that there is a method in admin to indicate which products should be included in the featured products displayed. Also that these products will be displayed randomly. I have been through all of the following areas in admin and found no method to specify that a product should be included:

• Manage Categories and all respective tabs available for an individual category
• Manage Products and all respective tabs available for an individual product
• Individual Product in admin that showed as featured on the home page
• System Configuration – sometimes tools are set up with some feature controls there
• Promotion
• CMS/Static Blocks
• CMS/Widgets

Am I misreading the code itself? Is there any are in admin I failed to review? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

class Jag_Featuredproduct_Block_Featuredproduct extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract

{

```
public function _prepareLayout()

{

    return parent::_prepareLayout();

}



public function getFeaturedproducts() {



    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 



    $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStore($storeId)->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($storeId)

    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

    //->addFieldToFilter('status',array('eq'=>1))

    ->addFieldToFilter('is_featured', array('eq' => 1));   



     //$p->getSelect()->order('updated_at DESC');

     $p->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));



     $p->getSelect()->limit(8);



     //echo $p->getSelect()->__toString(); exit();



    return $p->getData();



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is selecting all attributes and then filtering for the attribute "is_featured". So if it's not already available, create that attribute with code "is_featured" and add it to the attribute set, where you want to feature products. Then you can activate it in the specific product edit pages.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying with helpful information, it is appreciated!